# Parse a custom toml config

Tags: rust

In my project I parse a custom toml config with `toml-rs` which uses `serde` to deserialize the `.toml` file. Here is my config structure:

```
#[derive(Default, Debug, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd, Deserialize)]
pub struct InstanceConfig {
    pub other: Other,
}

#[derive(Default, Debug, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd, Deserialize)]
pub struct Other {
    pub welcome_channel: Option<String>,
    pub welcome_string: Option<String>,
}
```

And here is the code I don't like:

```
let mut instance = Instance::new();
let config: InstanceConfig = ...;
let server: Server = ...;
if let Some(channel_name) = config.other.welcome_channel {
    if let Some(welcome_string) = config.other.welcome_string {
        if let Some(channel_id) = self.get_channel_id_by_name(&channel_name, server.id) {
            instance.welcome = Some((welcome_string, channel_id));
        }
    }
}
```

Here are multiple `if let`s and I don't know how to refactor this and is it even possible. The main goal of this code is to set `instance.welcome` only under few circumstances (`welcome_channel` and `welcome_string` and both are set and then there is such channel id (`channel_id`) for such `channel_name`).

Comment: This looks like pseudo-code, due to the `...`. That being said, both `channel_name` and `welcome_string` can be matched in a single `if let` since they don't depend on each other, so you can get rid of one.

Comment: @Zeta This is not a pseudo-code, this is real code in a function which takes `InstanceConfig` and `Server` objects as arguments so I decided not to write what they are and just mention them. Also, how can I merge two `if let`s as you say?

Comment: Give me about two hours till my VC tools are installed and I can check whether everything works as intended. Sorry.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Yes, this question is exactly about refactoring the code. Also, I don't know what else title could fit your requirements. Could you provide some example? I have also followed your link but it contains very little information about naming, it just says "it must not be obvious and meaningless". And personally I do understand that it should be so and not be "too broad". But is it?

Comment: Also, I was unable to find any refactoring site on stackexchange and found such question and answer on it which says that you may ask refactoring questions here, in `codereview`. So the title clearly asks a question and reflects intentions. is not it?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy As suggested: " state the task accomplished by the code". This code is supposed to do something, right? So use that to compose a title, e.g. "deserializing a toml configuration file"

Comment: If the question had been about code review - yes, I should have done as you say. But the question is not about review but about refactoring, so the title imho should clearly reflect refactoring intentions.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy This is Code Review.SE, not Code Refactor.SE, we're giving you a platform, and so you should follow our rules.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP states they are **not looking for code review**.

Comment: @Shepmaster that's okay. I have posted a question in inappropriate stackexchange website. I agree it is off-topic. But I think refactoring is a subtask of codereview and by this reason stackexchange does not have separate `refactoring` website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could take advantage of pattern matching on tuples to merge two `if let` that don't depend on each other:

```
if let (Some(channel_name), Some(welcome_string)) = 
    (config.other.welcome_channel, config.other.welcome_string) {
    ...
}
```

Now that we have both `channel_name` and `welcome_string`, let's have a look at the next block:

```
if let Some(channel_id) = self.get_channel_id_by_name(&channel_name, server.id) {
    instance.welcome = Some((welcome_string, channel_id));
}
```

If we `get_channel_id_by_name` return `Some`, we will set `instance.welcome` to `Some`, otherwise to `None`. That sounds like a a job for [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map):

```
instance.welcome = self.get_channel_id_by_name(&channel_name, server.id)
    .map(|channel_id| (welcome_string, channel_id));
```

Together, we would end up with this:

```
if let (Some(channel_name), Some(welcome_string)) =
    (config.other.welcome_channel, config.other.welcome_string) {
    instance.welcome = self.get_channel_id_by_name(&channel_name, server.id)
        .map(|channel_id| (welcome_string, channel_id));
}
```

Alternatively, we can pattern match on `Other`:

```
if let Other {
           welcome_channel: Some(name),
           welcome_string: Some(message),
           ..
       } = config.other {
    instance.welcome = self.get_channel_id_by_name(&name, server.id)
        .map(|channel_id| (message, channel_id));
}
```